# How to read/view the content of bash function?

Tags: bash

We can always view `alias` value by using `alias` command.

```
wolf@linux:~$ alias al='grep "$1" file.txt'
wolf@linux:~$ alias al
alias al='grep "$1" file.txt'
wolf@linux:~$
```

Unfortunately, `grep` doesn't work with alias. Not sure what was the problem. If you know the problem and solution, please let me know.

```
wolf@linux:~$ al
random text
abc def jkl
random text
abc ghi jkl
random text
wolf@linux:~$ 

wolf@linux:~$ al abc
file.txt:random text
file.txt:abc def jkl
file.txt:random text
file.txt:abc ghi jkl
file.txt:random text
grep: abc: No such file or directory
wolf@linux:~$
```

So I decided to use function.

```
wolf@linux:~$ func(){ grep "$1" file.txt; }
wolf@linux:~$ func
random text
abc def jkl
random text
abc ghi jkl
random text
wolf@linux:~$
```

It works.

```
wolf@linux:~$ func abc
abc def jkl
abc ghi jkl
wolf@linux:~$
```

But there is another problem now, I've defined a few functions and forgot their content.

Is there a way to view the content of the function, probably something similar with `alias al` command above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`type NAME` (or `type -a NAME`  if more than one command is defined with the same name) will do it:

```
$ func(){ grep "$1" file.txt; }
$ type func
func is a function
func () 
{ 
    grep --color=auto "$1" file.txt
}
```

Comment: `typeset -fp func` will show you the source code without the `func is a function` prelude.

Comment: I *knew* there was some way to print just the contents, thanks @user414777

Answer (score 3):

To view the code of a function run `set`.

Your alias does not work because `$1` does not work in aliases.  Aliases are just text replacement, they are not functions.  So if you have the alias

```bsh
alias foo='bar "$1" baz'
```

and then type `foo` on the command line the shell will behave as if you typed `bar "$1" baz`.  And if you type `foo something` the shell will execute `bar "$1" baz something` and not `bar something baz`.

Answer (score 2):

This would be a tangential answer. To make the `grep` alias work without a function.

Borrowed and adapted from [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23681972/6005145):

```bsh
alias al='grep file.txt -f - <<<'
```

Then:

```bsh
$ cat file.txt
aaa
bbb
ccc
$ al a
aaa
```

> The `-f -` tells grep to use expressions from a file, but since thew
> file here is `-`, then the expressions are read from stdin.  Then we
> use a bash here-string to redirect the contents of a string to the
> stdin.  This allows the `grep` expression to be placed right at the end
> of the command, which is what we need for an alias to work.

Comment: Or use stdin to read the file: `alias al='grep < file.txt'`

Comment: Thanks, both works, learned new trick from both answer.